# combining two mysql table by row

Tags: mysql, r, rbind

If I have two tables `table_a` and `table_b` with the same structure say:

```
index: integer (primary key)
column_a: varchar(255)
column_b: varchar(255)
```

Both tables has 10 rows.

I want to "stack" (or `rbind` in R terms) the two tables, so that the resulting table has the same structure with 20 rows, is it possible? And how to do it if it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are looking for `union all` ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid this could be an answer. OP, please, provide example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use union in it as

```
  Select * from table1 
  UNION
  Select * from table2
```